# Script only enters the innermost while loop once

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I have this script that I'm using the get the status code of a set of links. Upon finding the first link with status code 206, it will output the contents and terminate.

My problem is that the innermost `while` loop will never trigger a second time. Once the innermost loop does its first set of iterations, the middle `while` loop will execute all of its iterations then terminates. I left a few `echo` statements in to help with debugging, and I swapped the actual URL with a dummy URL.

```
current_url=http://example.com
# $(date +%Y%m%d)

chr() {
  [ "$1" -lt 256 ] || return 1
  printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$1")"
  return 
}

i=122
j=122
k=122
lower_bound=47

while [  $i -gt $lower_bound ]; do
    first=$(chr $i)

    while [  $j -gt $lower_bound ]; do
        second=$(chr $j)

        while [  $k -gt $lower_bound ]; do
            third=$(chr $k)

            status=$(curl -so /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $current_url)
            echo Status: $status Hash:$first$second$third
            if [[ "$status" == "206" ]]
            then
                curl -O $current_url
                exit
            fi

            if [[ $k == 97 ]]
            then
                k=91
            elif [[ $k == 65 ]]
            then
                k=58
            fi
            let k=k-1 
        done

        echo $j
        if [[ $j == 97 ]]
        then
            j=91
        elif [[ $j == 65 ]]
        then
            j=58
        fi
        let j=j-1 
    done

    echo $i
    if [[ $i == 97 ]]
    then
        i=91
    elif [[ $i == 65 ]]
    then
        i=58
    fi
    let i=i-1 
done
```

Some sample output into a file:

```
Status: 200 Hash:zzz #innermost loop
Status: 200 Hash:zzy
Status: 200 Hash:zzx
...
Status: 200 Hash:zz2
Status: 200 Hash:zz1
Status: 200 Hash:zz0 #innermost loop runs to end
122
121 #middle loop continues without returning to innermost loop
120
...
50
49
48 #middle loop executes to end
122
121 #outer loop executes without returning to middle loop
120
...
50
49
48 #outer loop executes to end and script terminates
```

Comment: Where do you reset `k` to its initial value? Or `j`?

Comment: @EtanReisner I never did. That was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`j` and `k` where never reset to their initial values. After doing so, the loop issue was fixed.

*Credit goes to @etan-reisner for pointing this out in a comment. Should he post his comment as an answer, I will accept it.*